# TKNN invariant changes due to continuous deformation of parameter space

Tags: quantum-hall-effect, topological-insulators

Naively, I would assume that a topological invariant remains invariant under continuous deformations of whatever space the invariant belongs to. In the case of topological insulators, this space is the space of parameters characterizing the material and its environment. If we consider the magnitude of a magnetic field incident onto a material supporting metallic edge states a parameter, then why does the Chern number (TKNN invariant) change when $|\textbf{B}|$ is increased smoothly and slowly? Since the Hall conductivity experiences sharp increases due to slow increase of magnetic field, the Chern number must be increasing sharply (by integer jumps), signifying sharp changes in the topology of the parameter space. What parameter is changing so drastically in response to the increasing magnetic field?

Comment: Let me just say a few words about this. You first have to define your space slightly more carefully. For topological insulators of symmetry class $G$, the relevant space is the space of Hamiltonians which are gapped (very important) and invariant under symmetry G. You can parametrize such a Hamiltonian (and thus this space) by material dependent parameters and so on. So the topological invariant will not change as long as when changing the parameters, you don't close the energy gap and don't break the symmetry $G$.

Comment: Now, the reason why the topological invariant changes when a parameter (say $\mathbf B$) is changed smoothly, is that although this is a smooth deformation of the space of all Hamiltonians, it is not smooth on the space of **gapped** Hamiltonians with symmetry $G$. Meaning that the topological invariant will change if, for example, at some value of $\mathbf B$, the energy gap closes, since you go outside of space of gapped Hamiltonians. This is just the point of phase transition.

Comment: Actually it is possible to demonstrate that changing $|B|$ increases the particle density, i.e., the filling level, i.e., the Fermi energy.